# Apache rewrite proxy only homepage

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress, mod-proxy

I've tried various regular expressions (`^/$`, `^index.php$`, `^$`) to rewrite/proxy just the homepage of a WordPress website through `.htaccess`. For the record I have the appropriate modules loaded to accomplish this and can do it for other paths with specific regular express, but just not the homepage. Other answers have indicated `^$` and `^/$` will work, but it's not working for me. How is it possible to target get just the homepage?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ http://some-other-domain.com [P]
```

The end goal is to serve a page from another website for just the homepage. Perhaps there is a better approach?

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly - what happens? Do you get an error? Incorrect response? Seemingly nothing? Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file - you may have a conflict. (_Aside:_ A pattern like `^/$` certainly won't work in `.htaccess` and a pattern like `^index.php$` will match _everything_ in the directive you posted.)

Comment: @MrWhite "not working" means I can't get http://some-other-domain.com served through "main-domain.com." I've stripped down the .htaccess to include only the rules above to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following instead, at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://some-other-domain.com/ [P]
```

The `RewriteBase` and `RewriteEngine` directives are not required here. The `RewriteEngine` presumably already appears later in the file as part of the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block (the order is not important).

Note the slash suffix on the *substitution* string. This is a *required* part of the URL (you can't have an empty URL-path). If you omit it here, then something else must "fix" it later. In the case of an external redirect then the *browser* would "fix" it, but there is no "browser" here.

This matches both an empty URL-path and `index.php` (in case mod_dir is issuing the subrequest for the directory index *before* mod_rewrite sends the request through mod_proxy). The *condition* that checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is necessary in this instance to avoid proxying *everything*, since the WordPress front-controller rewrites everything to `index.php`. The condition ensures that only direct requests are matched, not rewritten requests.

*Aside:* A `RewriteRule` *pattern* like `^/$` will never match in a `.htaccess` context. This would only work if the directive was used in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context.